# Cat Command not working in a loop

Tags: shell, for-loop, terminal, cat

I have a Cat command within a for loop. The for loop goes through a bunch of folders.

Within my code, I basically commented everything out, except the cat command and the outer loop. Once I comment out the loop, the cat command works. Everything works when I remove the cat command too and what's in it.

The error I get is: syntax error: unexpected end of file. It always refers to the last line, being the done in this case.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $HOME/filedirectory
for k in *; do
    cat > $HOME/mongodb/bin/script1.js << EOF
       ##commented out stuff
    EOF
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove space before EOF in closing:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $HOME/filedirectory
for k in *; do
    cat > $HOME/mongodb/bin/script1.js << EOF
       ##commented out stuff
EOF
done
```

As per `man bash`:

> If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter.  This allows here-docu-
>          ments within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

So you can change the heredoc operator to `<<-`. then you can indent both the heredoc and the delimiter with tabs. (**no spaces**)